# How to verify the relationship between the generating function and the moment generating function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions

I calculated the Moment Generating Function of a Poisson random variable: $N \sim \mathrm{Poiss}(\lambda)$
$$
E[e^{t N}] =  \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty e^{t k} \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k }{k!} = e^ {\lambda[e^{t}-1]}
$$

I also calculated the Generating Function of $N$:
$$
E[t^{N}]  =  e^ {\lambda[{t}-1]}
$$

Now, I want to verify the relationship between the Generating Function (GF) and the Moment Generating Function (MGF).

Specifically, I want to check that GF = MGF $\cdot \log t$.

In other words, GF / MGF should be equal to $\log t$.

But when I work it out, I am stuck at the below point:

The GF divided by the MGF gives me:

GF / MGF  =  $$ e^ {\lambda[t - e^{t}]} $$

I tried various ways to see if this reduces to $\log t$, but my methods didn't seem to proceed.  Any advice or insights would be very helpful here.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that your result depends on $\lambda$, whereas $\log t$ does not. Furthermore if $\lambda>0$, your result tends to $0$ as $t\to+\infty$, whereas $\log t \to +\infty$ as $t\to+\infty$. Why do you expect a $\log t$?

Comment: The relation you're looking for is probably $MGF(t) = GF(e^t)$. It's indeed hard to see why you expect the log to be in the division result.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes that's correct!